VB6 declare a constant to be used for array size declaration
I have the following code in Visual Basic, I think it's VB6 or anyway a very old version.
I have an array, it's 7-elements long, so its index is 6. Declaration and use:
Dim my_array(6)
my_array(0) = "blabla"
my_array(1) = "blabla"
my_array(2) = "blabla"
my_array(3) = "blabla"
my_array(4) = "blabla"
my_array(5) = "blabla"
my_array(6) = "blabla"

Dim i
For i = 0 To 6
   ' do something

As you can see, if for some reason in any part of the code the 6 will be changed (for example, there is a new element) and in any of the iterations in the script one will forget to change 6 to 7, will be a bug.
To avoid that, I want to replace 6 with a constant, so I try to declare a constant:
Const ARRAY_LAST_INDEX = 6

Dim my_array(ARRAY_LAST_INDEX)
my_array(0) = "blabla"
my_array(1) = "blabla"
my_array(2) = "blabla"
my_array(3) = "blabla"
my_array(4) = "blabla"
my_array(5) = "blabla"
my_array(6) = "blabla"

Dim i
For i = 0 To ARRAY_LAST_INDEX
   ' do something

What I get: "Error: Expected integer constant"
Is it possible to declare a constant to use in array declaration in old VB, as is done in "normal" programming languages?
I searched for help, but I find little for older versions, and very basic examples. And often they just work for newer versions. My version should be VB6 and i cannot change that.
EDIT 1
Some non-working attempts I already tried to declare the constant:
Const ARRAY_LAST_INDEX = 6
Const ARRAY_LAST_INDEX as Integer = 6
Const ARRAY_LAST_INDEX = 6 as Integer

EDIT 2
One solution (or workaround) is to use Redim; probably it does not matter if ARRAY_LAST_INDEX is const or not:
Const ARRAY_LAST_INDEX = 6

Dim my_array()
Redim my_array(ARRAY_LAST_INDEX)


Use: For i = 0 to Ubound(my_array)

@JohnEason The error is at declaring the array, not at iterating. And even then, if you want to iterate safely, then it's For i = LBound(my_array) To UBound(my_array).

Ok. It should also be Ubound(my_array)-1 in this case as the lower bound is zero. - I'm a bit rusty nowadays, having not programmed for a couple of years. :^(

@JohnEason It shouldn't have -1, no. UBound is what it says on the tin, the upper bound. Not the number of elements in the array.

In this case though the lower bound (and default when declaring an array in VB6) is 0 so for an array of 6 items you count from 0 to 5 which is Ubound - 1 ! :^)

@JohnEason No, because in the case of an array with indices from 0 to 5 LBound will return 0 and UBound will return 5.

Thanks, in case of next version i will try UBound. Unfortunately, in most of cases the "too advanced" features like this are only in versions of VB newer than the one I must use. Example: my_array.GetUpperBound(0) does not work with "my" old version
